# Single-line classes

Tags: css

A colleague just added this to our project.

```html
<ol class="numbered-list list-inside" start="1">
```

```css
.numbered-list
{
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
.list-inside
{
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Am I missing something here or is this just as bad as inline CSS? How do I explain this to my colleague?

**Edit** Perhaps my question is misunderstood. Shouldn't it be something like this instead?

```html
<ol class="info-list" start="1">
```

```css
.info-list
{
    list-style-type: decimal;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

The point I'm trying to make is, the class names just represent the rule they apply. So if you want to change the representation of the list, you have to change the HTML (or change the CSS so you end up with a class name that does the opposite of the rule it contains).

**Another edit** Perhaps this will further help you understand my question.

```html
<p class="red">Hello</p>
```

```css
.red
{
    color: red;
}
```

Now, you want to change the text to be green. See the issue?

Comment: Looks fine to me, although adding `start="1"` is redundant.

Comment: The only "not needed" code i see is that he uses 2 classes for nothing he can use just one and add the both style's like this: .numbered-list
{
    list-style-type: decimal;
    list-style-position: inside;
}

Comment: Downvoter, please explain.

Comment: I've added extra information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An [article](http://css-tricks.com/semantic-class-names/) confirms my doubts about this style. The most relevant example is this one:

```html
<div class="hyphenate"></div>
```

> **Unsemantic.** Trying to specify the behavior of the content inside, instead of describe what it actually is.

Answer (score 1):

If those classes are used separately in rest of your project this is ok. If there is no need to separate those styles such solution can be unnessesery.
Many times you add to one element several classes if they are used for different purposes.

Comment: In such case you are right, class name should be connected with context it is used. Ie. .MyGreatList .MyHeadingText .DialogTitle.